# 解答をいただいた方のうち、任意の方を選んで、自己回答を織り交ぜ、承認を行ってもよいでしょうか？

Tags: 討議

先日、[https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/45097/%e3%83%93%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%81%ae%e6%b7%b1%e3%81%95%e3%81%ab%e5%bf%9c%e3%81%98%e3%81%a6%e5%87%a6%e7%90%86%e3%82%92%e6%8c%af%e3%82%8a%e5%88%86%e3%81%91%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/45097/%E3%83%93%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E6%B7%B1%E3%81%95%E3%81%AB%E5%BF%9C%E3%81%98%E3%81%A6%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%82%92%E6%8C%AF%E3%82%8A%E5%88%86%E3%81%91%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

で質問をしたのですが、一件の解答をいただきました。その解答は、確実に私の疑問を解決するものではなかったのですが、SOFの本家で同様の質問をしたところ、問題が解決してしまいました。
　この場合、自己回答を行うことがセオリーなのでしょうけれども、その解答が、本家で得られた解答と、一部一致しており、まことに主観的な私的な感情なのですが、自己回答してチェックするよりは、その方の回答を改編して、その方の回答を承認したいなと思いました。
　
　たまにこのように思うような微妙なラインの回答を受ける事があるのですが、
　回答者の同意が得られたとして、こうしたことはしてもいいのでしょうか？
ひょっとしたら質問者の中にも、こうした経験がある方がいらっしゃるのではないか？
とも思ったことがあります。

また、一定の場合に認められるというような場合、その線引きはどこですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 既存の回答とは別に自己回答すべきかについて

既存の回答とは別に自己回答することについてですが、まず大前提として、スタック・オーバーフローにおいて回答は**承認**と**投票**という 2 通りのやり方で評価されます。回答が承認されたということはあくまで質問者自身はそれで納得したという目印でしかありません。多くの人の役に立った回答が別にあれば、それは投票によって評価されることになるでしょう。

そこで、たとえばこのような線引きができます：既存の回答に軽微な修正を加えることで役に立つ回答になるということであれば、コメント欄で追記要請をしつつその回答を承認すれば良いです。コメント欄では短すぎるなら、新しい回答として投稿するに充分な量の新情報でしょう。

もちろん、自己回答するにせよ既存の回答にリスペクトを示すことはとても良いことだと思います。多くの場合これは既存の回答へのプラス投票によって為すことができます。また、新しい回答で既存の回答に触れたり、[お礼を提示](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)したりするのも良いかもしれません。

### 英語版の回答を日本語版に持ってくることについて

本家で得られた英語の回答を翻訳して ja.SO に持ち込みたいということであれば、コミュニティ wiki として投稿する機能が使えそうです。回答欄の右下にあるチェックボックスを使うものです。

Stack Exchange ネットワークへの投稿は基本的に CC BY-SA として[ライセンスされている](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12527/341401)ので、「元の投稿者のプロフィールページへのリンク」と「元の投稿へのリンク」を含めていれば自由にスタック・オーバーフローへ翻訳・投稿できます。そして元々自分ではなく他者によって書かれた投稿だということをはっきりさせるためにコミュニティ wiki として投稿する、ということです。

Comment: コミュニティwikiは使った事がないので、少し慎重になります。今回の回答は、具体的な解決コードとして示されたものではなく、純粋な文章のみによって示された方法論であったため、どちらかと言えば自己回答するべきだと考えました。しかし思いとしては相変わらず回答者の回答を承認したいと思い続けています。もしご本人に具体的な解決策が当時頭になかった場合には、さりげなく本家から私のQ&Aを見付けて書き込んでくれることを願う気持もあります。少し様子見をします。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 本家の投稿を翻訳することについて: 個人的に、ソースを加えて翻訳を行ったのであるならば、それは価値のある投稿だし、それなりに労力がかかる作業なので、たとえそれが Community Wiki でなかったとしても、いいんじゃないかな(つまり、他の回答と同列にとりあつかってもよいのではないか)とは思います。